# How to get "revision history" of Google Fusion Tables?

Tags: google-drive, google-fusion-tables

In Google Docs, we can see the previous edits of a **Document** or **Spreadsheet** by clicking on *File* → **See revision history** (also <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>G</kbd>):

[image]

However, there doesn't seem to be a *See revision history* for **Fusion Tables**:

[image]

How can we access the revision history of a **Fusion Table**?

Comment: There simply is no revision history for fusion tables.

Comment: @VidarS.Ramdal, Seems weird that we have it for everything else but not in Fusion Tables their supposedly "better" feature.....